# How do I limit how far from a stockpile a dwarf is allowed to go to fetch items?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

Ideally, for a particular stockpile I want to be able to specify how far from the stockpile a dwarf is allowed to go for items.  Alternatively, it would be nice to be able to assign a stockpile to a burrow, and only allow it to collect items from that burrow.

For example, Say I'm excavating several veins of the same ore, and I want a localized stockpile at each one, but I don't want my Dwarves hauling ore across the map from one vein to another if the closer stockpile is full.

Is there a way to limit the range of a stockpile like this in v0.34.11?  Are there any mods out there that might do something similar?

Comment: Not in the mood to make a full answer, but have you considered quantum stockpiles using minecarts? This will prevent (partially) stockpiles from filling up.

Answer (score 2):

Short of creating burrows and confining dwarves to their respective burrows, each with its own stockpiles, there is no such feature in vanilla DF -- stockpiles will accept whatever they're set to accept from anywhere on the map (notwithstanding Forbidden or otherwise inaccessible items). Sorry. :(

I know of no mods that add this, either.

Answer (score 0):

For the example that you give (consolidating freshly mined ore), you can start by creating your local stockpile near the vein, and then create as many additional stockpiles as necessary to cover the area containing the mined ore. Add a "give to" link from each of those stockpiles to the first stockpile, and set all stockpiles including the first to take from links only.